# Android 10 inputStream times out on readLine

Tags: android, tcp

Simplified code:

```
Socket mysock = new Socket("192.168.1.1", 1234);
mysock.setSoTimeout(15000);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(mysock.getOutputStream())), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mysock.getInputStream()));
out.println("some text here");
String response = in.readLine(); // <-- throws Read timed out exception.
```

On Android versions lower than 10 this code works correctly. And no exception is being thrown.

On Android version 10 `readLine()` **always** throws an exception after 15s.

Am i doing something wrong with the socket streams?

Comment: And what is the exception? And the message?

Comment: `mysock.setSoTimeout(15000);` And what does 15000 mean?

Comment: The exception is "Read timed out" nothing more. 15000 is 15 seconds timeout ( expressed as milliseconds).

Comment: So now you know why it times out after 15 seconds. Strange that you do not realise. And if you do, then what is the question?

Comment: The question is: is there something different in Android 10 which makes this code time out? Because Android 6-7-8-9 devices (not emulators) are connecting to the **same** physical device using this same source code and they do not time out. Only the Android 10 device gets the time out exception (after those 15s pass of course). It would be extremely hard to debug the device they are all connecting to, so first thing is to find out if Android 10 has something to do with it.

Comment: Sorry, i dont know and cannot test by lack of suitable device. Why cant you reproduce it on an emulator for Android 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out phone was blocking the connection.

I am not sure if this is Android 10, or custom UI of the manufacturer that is doing this, but user had to click on a network and allow phone to complete connection.

This is all because target device does not have internet...